# ASP.NET Site Maps

Tags: sql, asp.net, xml, sitemap

Does anyone have experience creating SQL-based ASP.NET site-map providers?

I have the default XML file `web.sitemap` working properly with my Menu and SiteMapPath controls, but I'll need a way for the users of my site to create and modify pages dynamically.

I need to tie page viewing permissions into the standard `ASP.NET` membership system as well.

Answer (score 17):

The Jeff Prosise version from MSDN magazine works pretty well, but it has a few flaws:

`AddNode` freaks out with links to external sites on your menu (www.google.com, etc.)

Here's my fix in `BuildSiteMap()`:

```
SiteMapNode node = GetSiteMapNodeFromReader(reader);
string url = node.Url;
if (url.Contains(":"))
{
    string garbage = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();  // SiteMapNode needs unique URLs
    node.Url = "~/dummy_" + garbage + ".aspx";
    AddNode(node, _root);
    node.Url = url;
}
else
{
    AddNode(node, _root);
}
```

`SQLDependency` caching is cool, but if you don't want to make a trip to the DB everytime your menu loads (to check to see if the dependency has changed) and your menus don't change very often, then why not use `HttpRuntime.Cache` instead?

```
public override SiteMapNode RootNode
{
    get
    {
        SiteMapNode temp = (SiteMapNode)HttpRuntime.Cache["SomeKeyName"];
        if (temp == null)
        {
            temp = BuildSiteMap();
            HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert("SomeKeyName", temp, null, DateTime.Now.AddHours(1), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
        }
        return temp;
    }
}
```